# Unexpected Format on output of Cucumber HTML Report

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, cucumber, azure-pipelines

Using: Java, IntelliJ Community Edition, Azure DevOps, Ubuntu agent

Goal: To see accurate charted results of tests run either automatically when a pipeline is triggered, manually, or locally if a test is run locally in IDE

Steps so far:

- tried in-built vs test as there was tons of documentation on it but it seems that's only for windows agents (and possibly only .net?) neither of which is an option. [Link1.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/integrating-smoke-tests-into-your-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) [Link2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)
- [installed cucumber-html-report app](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejMaciejewski.azure-pipelines-cucumber) to azure devops
- [added cucumber dependencies](http://damienfremont.github.io/blog/20160509-test-cucumber_plugin_reporting_2/) to pom.xml and added the following code main runner

```java
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:LoginTest.feature", plugin={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json", "junit:target/cucumber.xml", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"})
```

- tests run and output but when you open the file, there's no formatting (just raw js, html, etc)

I've spent so long on what seems like such a simple task. I suspect it's at least in part due to the fact that I'm still familiarising myself with Cucumber and Azure DevOps so I'm hoping someone will see something I've missed. At this point I've thrown everything I could find on Google at it and nothing has worked successfully. Any and all help is very much appreciated

Comment: Did you try to download the file and view it in your browser? It may well be that the host includes headers that instruct your browser not to render the html.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer. It was this section:
"html:target/cucumber-html-report",
It was missing the .html at the end which is why I seemed to be following the instructions, getting some output, but not producing the expected result

Comment: Most articles show `@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty" , "html:target/cucumberReports"})` , but using cucumber-java version 6.10.2 that method doesn't work anymore. I added `.html` so it looks like this `@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty" , "html:target/cucumberReports.html"})` , now the HTML report can be displayed properly on browser.

Comment: For me, adding ".html" causes no report to be created.