# Pushing test complete results to cucumber via azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, cucumber, testcomplete, vstest

I have a test-complete project which is run via azure-devops, setup for CI. This project is linked to cucumber for the steps, as well as pushing results back up for reporting (we already have this setup and working for selenium, visual studio). The problem I am having is that I have multiple test runs in cucumber that are run using this single test-complete project.
When running manually there is no problem because we can manually switch between what test runs on cucumber our project currently pushes too. But with azure-devops that is not an option.
We currently create a .trx report that we use to bring results back into azure-devops but this report is not compatible with cucumber. I ran `/ListLoggers` to show all loggers available but none of these seem useable for pushing to cucumber using `hiptest-publisher`:

```
/ListLoggers
The following Test Logger Add-Ins are available:
Microsoft.TestPlatform.Extensions.BlameDataCollector.BlameLogger
Uri: logger://Microsoft/TestPlatform/Extensions/Blame/v1
FriendlyName: Blame
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.HtmlLogger.HtmlLogger
Uri: logger://Microsoft/TestPlatform/HtmlLogger/v1
FriendlyName: Html
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger.TrxLogger
Uri: logger://Microsoft/TestPlatform/TrxLogger/v1
FriendlyName: Trx
```

This is the part of the release pipeline that runs the tests:
[image]

I filter out tests to-be-run like so `FullyQualifiedName~SmokeTest`. So the question remains, how can I send results back up to cucumber, to specific test runs, from the single project via azure-devops without changing the test-run linked to in the test-complete project manually?

Comment: How about using [Cucumber HTML Report](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejMaciejewski.azure-pipelines-cucumber) task? Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805638/unexpected-format-on-output-of-cucumber-html-report) you can refer to.

Comment: @Jeff yep so we already make an html report as well that we save on a P-drive for testers to access, which is used as a more detailed report. the problem is that the devs all see and use cucumber to quickly and easily keep track of what is failing and what isnt therefore we need to be able to push our results back up as well